# Kendo UI Dropdownlist slow loading from a large datasource

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I'm using Kendo dropdownlist in a template. It loads a list of client names which are used to sign a record. The client name list has 8k entries.

The form loads ok but if I select the dropdownlist to change the client name it takes around 10 seconds for the list to appear. Is there something I can do to speed this up?

My datasource:

```
 var dsClients = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
          url: "/data/clients/key",
          dataType: "jsonp"
      },
      parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
          if (operation === "read") {
              return options;
          }
      }
    },
    serverSorting: true,
    sort: [{ field: "text", dir: "asc" }]
});
```

The element in my template:

```
 <input name="idclt_clm" data-bind="value:idclt_clm" data-value-field="value" 
   data-text-field="text" data-option-label="Select" data-source="dsClients" 
   data-role="dropdownlist" required validationMessage="Required" />
```

Comment: Does it make sense having a `dropdownlist` with 8k entries? Are your users willing to scroll down 8k entries? Wouldn't be better an `autocomplete`?

Comment: @OnaBai is right. DropDown isn't the right widget to use in that case.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 options that I know of.

1. You can add virtualization, which I just found from
   [Kendo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/virtualization).
2. You can turn of auto-bind and use a search filter that require 2 characters before it triggers a search. Below is how I've done it with asp.net and JS

   `@(Html.Kendo()
      .DropDownList()
      .Name("GridName")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control" })
      .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => 
          read.Action("YourFunction","YourController").Data("filterFunction"))
              .ServerFiltering(true))
      .MinLength(2)//number of characters for a valid search
      .Delay(250)//milliseconds delay to trigger search
      .AutoClose(false)
      .AutoBind(false)
      .IgnoreCase(true)
      .DataTextField("Text")
      .DataValueField("Value")
      .Placeholder("Enter at least 2 letters to search")
      .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
   )`

   `<script>
       function filterFunction() {
           return {
               text: $("#GridName").data("kendoDropDownList").input.val()
           };
       }
   </script>`

If the search is still slow, you can change the number of characters

Answer (score 1):

Well, what if you do both? Is maybe not the best aproach, but for me it worked.
I have a ComboBox that gets its info from an cascade event, so it would try either way to fill it up. So, after send the request to fill on server-side, I have a client-side event:

`.Filter(Contains).MinLength(n).Filtering("Action")`

Which will get to server throgh ajax to catch a Session var with the table/list with which you are trying to fill up your CB. Then filtering the desired list and send it back to your CB.